# Is there a way to programmatically get the source file and line number of an arbitrary MemberInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, symbols

I am writing a code analysis tool that uses reflection to validate a particular code base. When I encounter a type or member of interest I would like to load the symbols and extract the source file and line number where the member or type is defined. Is this possible? If so, how?

```
class SourceInfo
{
    public static SourceInfo GetFrom(MemberInfo member)
    {
        // What do I do here??
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static SourceInfo GetFrom(Type member)
    {
        // What do I do here??
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string SourceFilePath { get; private set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available symbol APIs are listed in this [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/10/08/symbol-apis.aspx).  I think the MDbg wrappers are your best bet for managed code.  I only tried the DIA sdk and wasn't thrilled.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/PdbParser.aspx) codeproject article has some information about retrieving information from PDB file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do this using reflection. To do this, you need the associated [program database file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903(VS.100).aspx) using the [Symbol API](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/09/30/corsym_idl.aspx).

Comment: Jason your links are dead. Perhaps you could summarise their content?